# retrieve the loop output in R

Tags: r

I am new in R and I'm dealing with loops. I have two matrices which are s1 (contain NA values) & B. I've trying this loop and having problem in retrieving the output.

```
m1<-function(s1,B)
 {
  for(i in 1:nrow(s1))
  { 
   if(is.na(s1[i,])==T) {mi<-rbind(mi,B[i,])}
  }
  print(mi)
 }
outB<-m1(s1,B)
```

I would like to have a new data.matrix formed from the row binding of the B[i,]. B[i,] should be matching with the s1[i,]. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that's not really the way to do this in R. This would replace that ugly loop:

```
m1<-function(s1,B)  # use vector indexing rather than a loop
 { mi <- B[ !is.na(s1),  ] # notice logical index and no "=="
  print(mi)
 }
outB<-m1(s1,B)
```

You really should not be rbinding successive rows together when all you really wanted to do was select a subset of rows. Extremely inefficient.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the function still doesn't return anything, which is probably the main problem OP was having.

Comment: @Marius Actually, `print` returns the object that it prints.